# C++ - getting null values in value read from registry

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

My application properly reads and writes to the registry. Now, I need to read a registry value from:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid
```

Here is my code:

```
bool GetWindowsID(string &winID)
{
    HKEY hKey = 0, hKeyType = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    bool status = false;
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwBufSize = 256;
    char value[256] = "\0";
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyType, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography", NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"MachineGuid", NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)value, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            status = true;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    winID.assign(value);
    return status;
}
```

I get the `guid` but in `value` array after each character their is a "\0" value due to which only first character of array gets assigned to string. This is wierd!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have built targeting Unicode and so the registry API is returning UTF-16 Unicode text. Instead of `char` use `wchar_t` and remember that each `wchar_t` element is 2 bytes wide.

Do also make sure that you account for the returned string not being null-terminated, as described in the documentation. You must take account of the value returned in `dwBufSize`.

Comment: Or use [`RegGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868.aspx) instead, which deals with the null terminator issue for you.

Answer (score 4):

> I get the guid but in value array after each character their is a "\0"
>   value due to which only first character of array gets assigned to
>   string. This is wierd!

This is because you are calling the Unicode version of `RegQueryValueEx()`, so the string is returned in Unicode (UTF-16).

You will have to use wide character parameters to get the value.

Change this line:

```
char value[256] = "\0";
```

To use `wchar_t` instead.